Spring STOMP and ping/pong timing
I'm working with Spring STOMP and rabbit mq. I'm deepening some disconnections issues probably disposed by a reverse proxy server.
I would like to know how has in charge the ping/pong handling, is this a specification of websocket protocol or of stomp protocol?
Where is possible to check the ping/pong timing in spring implementation?
Is a ping message suppose to reset the timeout of a reverse proxy like nginx?
